# How to include files (svg, fonts) referenced in css file with Aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have a very basic setup, derived from the contact manager tutorial. Trying to include a css file from an assets folder works but any file referenced from within that css file cannot be found when I run 'au run' as stated in the browser console.

I read that including fonts is not quite straight forward but am unsure as to how to do it correctly. 
Regarding SVG files I read that they basically are just text files and that I can include them from within the aurelia.json. However it did not work. Maybe I was missing something or the information I found was outdated.

brand.css:

```
body::after {
content: url("../../images/checkbox-unchecked.svg") [...]

@font-face {
font-family: 'Avenir Next';
src: url("../../fonts/avenir/avenir-regular-lat-ext.eot?#iefix"); [...]
```

app.html:

```
<require from="./assets/css/styleguide/brand.css"></require>
```

Folder structure:

```
src
 -assets  
   -css 
     -styleguide
        brand.css
   -fonts
     [...]
   -images
     [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

To wrap this up, this is how I finally managed to resolve the mentioned issues:

First I copied the assets folder to the root of my project, on the same level as the src folder.
Then I changed the cssPreprocessor setting in aurelia.json as follows:

```
"cssProcessor": { 
    ...
    "fileExtension": ".css", 
    "source": "assets/**/*.css"
},
```

This includes the css files from the specified folder and the internal references can now be resolved for both svg files and fonts.